# Laravel and Dropzone upload images

Tags: php, apache, laravel, upload

I have the following code on my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function(){

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; 

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", { 
        url: "{{url('subir-foto/'.$publicacion->id)}}",
        maxFilesize: 10,    
        dictDefaultMessage : "Click aquí para subir fotos",
        previewTemplate : '<div style="display:none"></div>',
    });


    myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
        $("#progress").show();
        $("#dropzone").hide();          
    });

    myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
        $("#bar").width(progress+'%');
        $("#percent").html(progress.toFixed(2)+'%');
        if (progress==100)
            $("#percent").html('Procesando...');        
    });

    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{URL::to('fotos/'.$publicacion->id)}}",          
            beforeSend: function(){$("#photos").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');},
            success: function(jsonData) {
              $("#photos").html(jsonData);
            }
        });     
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
        $("#progress").hide();
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#percent").html("0%");       
        $("#dropzone").show();          
    });     


});

</script>       



<div id="progress" style="display:none" class="progress progress-striped active">
      <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
        <div id="percent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


<button id="dropzone" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subir fotos</button>
```

And the controller that receive the image:

```
    public function storePhoto($id){

    $publicacion = Publicacion::findOrFail($id);

    //AUTENTIFICADORES DE USUARIO
    if(Auth::user()->id!=$publicacion->usuario_id && Auth::user()->perfil->id!=1) return Response::view('errors.401', array(), 401);

    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,gif|max:10240',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json($validator->messages()->first('file'), 403);
    }       

    $articulo_id = $publicacion->articulo->id;

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $nuevo_nombre = sha1(time().$file->getClientOriginalName()).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $upload_success = $file->move(upload_path($articulo_id),$nuevo_nombre);

    Image::make(upload_path($articulo_id).$nuevo_nombre)->fit(150, 100)->save(upload_path($articulo_id)."150x100_".$nuevo_nombre);
    Image::make(upload_path($articulo_id).$nuevo_nombre)->resize(450, null, function ($constraint) {$constraint->aspectRatio();$constraint->upsize();})->save(upload_path($articulo_id)."450x300_".$nuevo_nombre);

    $foto = new Foto;
    $foto->articulo_id = $articulo_id;
    $foto->nombre = $nuevo_nombre;
    $foto->save();
    $foto->posicion = Foto::where('articulo_id',$articulo_id)->max('posicion')+1;
    $foto->save();      

    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

The problem is:

When I try to upload many photos, I can only upload a maximum of 5 photos .... In my localhost using WAMP server i haven't this issue. The response is a 500 Error...

Please your feedback.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to increase the execution time for php. Keep this code over top of you php file or update your php ini file.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

You can also increase the `max_file_uploads` introduced in Php 5.3.1

[Max File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)

In case 
`max_file_uploads = 100` doesn't works for you then search for `suhosin.upload.max_uploads` and set it to

```
suhosin.upload.max_uploads=100
```

Hope this helps.